# NSScrollView generating scrollbar ghosts

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsscrollview

Please see attached image: http://i45.tinypic.com/fu8bpz.png

Has anyone every seen this kind of weird scroll bar behavior? I embedded a custom view in an NSScrollView. The scroll bars do not appear to be drawing correctly, and they also appear in the middle of my custom view. This happens on 10.6, yet not when I build on 10.7.  I also see it on 10.8. I have tried fixing this by building in XCode 3.2 as well as XCode 4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not balancing my [[NSGraphicsContext current] saveGraphicsState] with the appropriate [[NSGraphicsContext current] restoreGraphicsState]. Each [[NSGraphicsContext current] saveGraphicsState] must be balanced with a [… restoreGraphicsState] call, otherwise the GraphicsContext will be in an unpredictable state.